# Typo3 plugin $_GET parameters encoding

Tags: plugins, typo3, realurl

I need multiple `$_GET` parameters for my plugin. It results in rather long and ugly url which is neither readable nor user-friendly.

I have installed the `realurl` extension. It seems like I have to configure `realurl` for every page. Is there a simple way to solve it?

What are the methods available to inject data into controller rather than GET parameter?

Answer (score 1):

See realurl documentation:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/realurl/Realurl/Configuration/UrlEnDecodingBackground/Index.html

Or have a look at Georg Ringers documentation for example news extensions:
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html